# Angular 6 Module - angular not defined

Tags: javascript, angular

im very new to Angular and i started a test Project with Angular Cli.
All works fine but i have installed a 3.rd Party Module (angular-ui-carousel).
Now i get following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at Module../node_modules/angular-ui-carousel/dist/ui-carousel.js (ui-carousel.js:21)
```

ui.carousel.js (only the first rows..)

```js
'use strict';
(function (angular) {
  // Create all modules and define dependencies to make sure they exist
  // and are loaded in the correct order to satisfy dependency injection
  // before all nested files are concatenated by Gulp

  // Config
  angular.module('ui.carousel.config', []).value('ui.carousel.config', {
    debug: true
  });

  // Modules
  angular.module('ui.carousel.providers', []);
  angular.module('ui.carousel.controllers', []);
  angular.module('ui.carousel.directives', []);
  angular.module('ui.carousel', ['ui.carousel.config', 'ui.carousel.directives', 'ui.carousel.controllers', 'ui.carousel.providers']);
})(angular); //error points here
'use strict';
```

is there any workaround to run this module in Angular 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing Angular and AngularJS.

`angular.` references are applicable to AngularJS(AngularJS 1.x)

And Angular(Angular 2+) don't have `angular.` references.

[**angular-ui-carousel**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-carousel) is a library for AngularJS and **NOT Angular**

Please consider using some other library that is meant for Angular, like [**ng-simple-slideshow**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-simple-slideshow)

Comment: Thx. I dont saw this. If anyone looking for a carousel module, try this: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/79/A-Quick-and-Easy-Angular-Carousel-in-a-Few-Minutes-(Angular-2-and-4+)